# I am trying to put a intent to my app so i can navigate

Tags: java, android

I am trying this intent so I can navigate from one activity to another activity but I'm getting this error `

```
final Button btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.addEmp);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

            if(v.getId() == R.id.addEmp){
                Intent intent = new 
Intent(getCallingActivity(),AddEmployee.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });`
```

there is a red line under

```
 (getCallingActivity(),AddEmployee.class);
```

there error says

> cannot resolve constructor

Is anything wrong with this

```
 (getCallingActivity(),AddEmployee.class);
```

statement?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(curruntactivityname.this,AddEmployee.class);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your line from

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getCallingActivity(),AddEmployee.class);
```

to this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this,AddEmployee.class);
```

OR

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddEmployee.class);
```

**Edit**

> Whats wrong with getCallingActivty()?

getCallingActivity() returns `ComponentName` while intent constructor requires `Context` as a first argument.

Hope this will work